firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler on iOS not working?
In Flutter, I have successfully received push notifications on both Android and iOS, regardless of the app's state. However, I am working on a feature that saves the notification to the device's local storage upon receiving a push notification, then displays it as a list of notifications within the app. This feature seems to work fine on Android, but on iOS, it doesn't function when the app is in the background or terminated. It only works when the app is in the foreground. What adjustments should I make? Should it be in AppDelegate.swift or somewhere else?
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    await saveNotification(message);
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    logger.d(message.toMap());
    if (message.notification != null) {
      await saveNotification(message);
      if (GlobalVariables.navState.currentContext != null) {
        Navigator.of(GlobalVariables.navState.currentContext!)
            .pushNamed("AnnouncementDetail", arguments: message);
      }
    }
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.setAutoInitEnabled(false);
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await saveNotification(message);
}

Future<void> saveNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  List<String>? notifications = prefs.getStringList('notifications') ?? [];
  String formattedTime = dateTime2String(message.sentTime ?? DateTime.now());

  final String newNotification =
      "$formattedTime\n${message.notification?.title ?? ''}\n${message.notification?.body ?? ''}";
  bool isDuplicate =
      notifications.any((notification) => notification == newNotification);
  if (!isDuplicate) {
    notifications.add(newNotification);
    await prefs.setStringList('notifications', notifications);
  }
}

import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps
import UserNotifications
import BackgroundTasks
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging



@main
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

  let gcmMessageIDKey = "..."

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("...")

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    if(FirebaseApp.app() == nil){
      FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    // [START set_messaging_delegate]
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    // [END set_messaging_delegate]

    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    // [START register_for_notifications]

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
      options: authOptions,
      completionHandler: { _, _ in }
    )

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                            didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                            fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
  }
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
  // [START refresh_token]
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")

    let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(
      name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
      object: nil,
      userInfo: dataDict
    )
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
  }

  // [END refresh_token]
}


I have tried many ways, but it still doesn't work.
